# bool(input()) всегда возвращает True

Tags: python, циклы, input, bool

Работал над заданием и возникла ошибка. Не смотря на то что я ввожу в `is_good_employee` всегда возвращается `True` (Это можно увидеть на скрине в меню отладки).

[image: worker = is_good_employee= True]

Я бы мог переписать код, но очень интересно почему же так происходит, буду искренне благодарен за помощь.

```py
workers = []


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, on_vacation, salary, is_good_employee):
        self.name = name
        self.on_vacation = on_vacation
        self.salary = salary
        self.is_good_employee = is_good_employee
    
    def info(self):
        print(f"работник {self.name} получает {self.salary} и находится {self.on_vacation}. ")


for i in range(0, 5):
    worker = Employee(name=input("Имя сотрудника >>> "), salary=input("Заработная плата >>> "),
                      on_vacation=input("Работа >>> "), is_good_employee=bool(input()))
    
    if not worker.is_good_employee:
        workers.append("Уволен")
    else:
        workers.append(worker.name)

    print(workers)
```

Comment: А что вы туда вводите?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В отличие от `int`, `float` и других похожих функций, `bool` не конвертирует строки `"True"` или `"False"` в булевые значения `True` или `False` соответственно, а проверяет любой переданный объект на "истинность".

В частности, `bool` от любой непустой коллекции вернет `True`, от пустой - `False`. Поэтому в случае строк он вернет `False` только для пустой строки:

```
>>> bool("sdfwt")
True

>>> bool("False")
True

>>> bool("")
False
```

Если нужно чтобы `"True"` преобразовывалось в `True`, можно просто сравнивать введенную строку со строкой `"True"`:

```
is_good_employee = input() == "True"
```

Я бы еще сделал, чтобы проверка была без учета регистра:

```
is_good_employee = input().casefold() == "true"
```

тогда будет срабатывать и на "True", и на "true", и на "tRuE".

Документация:

- [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)
- [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) - как определяется, что объект "истинный" или "ложный" при передаче в `bool` или при использовании объекта в качестве условий в `if` или `while`.